# Reasons of Why a block of Code with IF ELSE might be skipped in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing a problem where a block of code with IF ELSE statement is skipped by Javascript, like literally there is no output in the Console, ofcourse I have placed a `console.log()` in the statement. So I was wondering why does this happen ? What are the reasons ? Are there some general guidelines for using IF..ELSE in specific places ? Is it something related to a scope of a statement ?  By the way I am using the IF .. ELSE for assigning a Bool Variable, some thing like this :

```
Animation1 = (buttonPressed == true) ? false : true ;
Animation2 = (buttonPressed == true) ? false : true ;
Animation3 = (buttonPressed == true) ? false : true ;
```

Something like that, anyways I just want to know, are there any general reasons why a Block of Code like this will be skipped in Javascript even though there are no errors in the console ?

[**JS Fiddle** with actual code](http://jsfiddle.net/9eb84ahv/39/)

Comment: Why do you need a ternary expression? Why not just use `Animation1 = !buttonPressed;` ?

Comment: Post the actual code, the expected and actual results.

Comment: Where is the `if ... else` bit?

Comment: @Mureinik Ahaan thats something new for me, I dint know we could do that. but is that similar to a conditional statement.

Comment: @PM77-1 well I am actually working on it as soon I get it done I will post a fiddle that simulates the issue.

Comment: @EdHeal Apologies for that actually, the problem persists even if I use an IF...else condition, the code is not executed and there are no errors in the developers console.

Comment: You assign `velocityenable` once when document loads and I do not see where it could change its value.  Why do you expect it to change?

Comment: okay the thing is that Velocity 'Scroll' is kind of hard to control, especially when you have a smooth scroll functionality, so I hade assign velocity enabled in the beginning with assumption that the user scrolls manually instead of smooth scrolling to the bottom of the page hence velocityenabled = true in the beginning. Later it becomes false when buttonPressed = true so that the animation stops and the smooth scroll happens smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not getting any console.log statements, it's likely you have errors in your JavaScript code or code preceeding it is preventing your if else statements from executing. This works fine for me.

```
var buttonPressed = false;
var Animation1 = !buttonPressed;
var Animation2 = !buttonPressed;
var Animation3 = !buttonPressed;
console.log(Animation1);
console.log(Animation2);
console.log(Animation3);
```

Comment: codes preceding it ? Hmm... the chrome developer console, does not show any error. So is it something like a logical error ?

Comment: I'd say it's a logic error then. Have you tried inserting debugger; statements in your code to see what's going on? I'd make sure that your buttonPressed variable is correct, or even being reached.

Comment: here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9eb84ahv/39/ , its about automatically scrolling to a point when a scroll position is reached. Please forgive me for my coding style its very bad as i am still a beginner. do let me know if you require some more information.